# Translate to specified language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I know I can translate to current website language with [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, but I need translate to specified (not current) language, my site has three languages and I want get English of some of the worlds in some template files when current language is French. **How can I get translate of string according to specified language instead of current language?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) documentation you can pass specified language it `t()` function.

As Example below code return French translate of `language` string without consider current site language.

```
  $fr_value = t('language', array(), array('langcode' => 'fr'));
```