# How to get a custom field label in a specific language?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

In order to get the label of a field I just do :

```
$fii = field_info_instance('node', 'field_app_area', 'products');
$label = $fii['label'];
```

But it returns the label in the original language of the field, not the current user language.

I have seen some code here to get the translated label from the $content variable of a node template, but I don't have the template variables available.

So my question is either : how do I get the label translation or how do I get the $content (or similar) variable available without being on a template.

Comment: Hello, can you indicate the drupal version that you're using? Also, you can consider passing it through t(). Quick and dirty solution though.

Comment: Forgot that, it's drupal 7, added the tag. Also whoever down-voted the question I would be grateful to know why, so I can improve it.

Comment: @drcelus it's good question vote up .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that using t(), doesn't work for translated field labels.

To get the translated field label text (in the current language), just use the [`i18n_field_translate_property`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21i18n%21i18n_field%21i18n_field.module/function/calls/i18n_field_translate_property/7) function

```
  $field_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_application_area', 'products');
  $label = i18n_field_translate_property($field_instance, 'label');
```

Or, for a specific language :

```
  $label = i18n_field_translate_property($field_instance, 'label', 'fr');
```

Found on this [related answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/86180/5783).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fii = field_info_instance('node', 'field_app_area', 'products');
$label = t($fii['label']);
```

and [according to this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184080/translate-to-specified-language)  if you want to get on specified language try

```
$fii = field_info_instance('node', 'field_app_area', 'products');
$en_label = t($fii['label']);
$fr_label = t('language', array(), array('langcode' => 'fr'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for translated field labels.

Comment: @drcelus I didn't test it before, vote up for your answer ,it's correct answer.